# php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to set up and learn Laravel following [this course](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/4)

When I try to use the command `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables whe  
  re table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]                                                                            
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have looked for answers. I figured I may have to make some changes in the `.env` file, but I don't know what, and nothing I have tried so far has worked.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, not a Mac OS X as in the video, so I wonder what should I do differently? Is there some MySQL setting I did not set correctly?

Comment: Is your mysql service running??? and also check the mysql credentials in `.env` file

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` for this command I get: `[ ok ] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.` Still the error is the same. What credentials should I check?

Comment: Does the laravel user exist in the database? Have you tried creating a table laravel on your database and adding all privileges to the user?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have a user named 'laravel'.
You should change the DB_USERNAME to the one you're actually using to access your DB.
Mostly it's root by default so the changes in .env should be

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem with my plesk ubuntu 18.04 remote server. In your .env file put double quotes around your database password and username then run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME="xyz"    
DB_PASSWORD="123"
```

I had never come across this problem before.

Comment: Thanks. That solved for me also on Plesk with Ubuntu 18.04 remote server

Comment: This solve my problem!, i am updating a project from an old Laravel release and the credentials was running OK without the double quotes.

Comment: Thank you! Adding double quotes on the username and password worked. My migrations ran successfully afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, Highly Appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks, That solved my problem with Windows 10, Laravel 8.6.8, MariaDB 10.3.32.

Comment: You are still solving a strange problem in 2022! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! strange issue. I mean it doesn't matter any other day if you put " "  or not.

Comment: Thanks, but i wonder how did you know that

Answer (score 24):

If you are trying to run this command with homestead, you need to make sure you change the values of the following environmental variables within the `.env` file to:

```
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**After you have changed the values, make sure to run the following two commands before you do anything else:**

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: For anyone using Laravel 7, homestead and mysql 8+  -- this is the solution!

Comment: This worked for me as well. This was from a fresh install of Homestead.

Comment: This is the answer on Laravel 8+

Answer (score 22):

if your DB_PASSWORD contains # symbol then enclose it like this

```
DB_PASSWORD="dfdf#523"
```

Comment: Still a valid answer on Laravel 10

Comment: What a classic - I spent 3 hours debugging our ansible scripts for the server setup. I was blaming colleagues for their code. But in the end it was one symbol :D

Answer (score 13):

In my case it solved with using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MAMP and the default root username/pw, your .env file database configuration should use 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1 and 'root' for BOTH the username and password:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same problem. Updated my root password in mysql using

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '.....'
```

where the updated password had no special character '#'. Updated it in the .env file. Then successfully ran `php artisan migrate` in the terminal.

Comment: As an additional info,  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the password was already put in semicolons in the .env file.

Comment: I surrounded it with quotes `DB_PASSWORD="5bHKx$$J#"`

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a new user in `phpmyadmin`, eg. `username-xyz`, `password-123`
2. Create a new database eg. `dbname`
3. Update your `.env` file like this:

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=dbname
   DB_USERNAME=xyz    
   DB_PASSWORD=123
   ```
4. Now clear your cache using `php artisan cache:clear`
5. Finally, try migrating your tables with `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 4):

I had situation when server didn't saw update .env file and `php artisan cache:clear` not help, but just was needed refresh server `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. What finally worked for me was performing [Method 2 on this page](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/).

Through my struggle, I learned that there are 4 different places where you can set a password for the `root` of the MySQL installation that comes with XAMPP. Setting the password in only 1 or 2 of these places alone is not enough. This is what I did to be able to perform my initial migration:

1. In the Laravel `.env` file, in the `DB_...` section.
2. In `localhost:[your Apache port]/phpmyadmin`, via User accounts -> root -> Edit privileges -> Change password.
3. In `localhost:[your Apache port]/phpmyadmin`, via the method described in [Method 2 on this page](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/).
4. In your `config.inc.php` file, which for me (on MacOS) was in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. This method is also described in [Method 2 on this page](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/).

And then **restart MySQL and your web (Apache) server**.

Be aware that after you successfully harmonize your passwords and try once again to migrate, you may get error output that looks almost the same as the Access Denied password error. However, this is a different error related to string lengths. [See here for how to fix that issue.](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on MAMP, check your port number as well. Generally, it should look like this:

```
Host    localhost
Port    8889
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue, it was because I forgot my local environment was running mysql on a port other than 3306.  For me, it was 3307.  If you are using XAMPP, I would check what port you are using and make sure it matches your .env file.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the PHPMyAdmin password then you need to set something like on .ENV file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

If no password set then you can leave DB_PASSWORD as blank
DB_PASSWORD=

both are done still not work then it caches issue for fixing it you need to `delete` config file which is located to **`bootstart/cache/config.php`**
after that php artisan config: cache work and same file `auto-generated`

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was fixed by adding '' to the user and password fields like so:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=someCoolDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME='someCoolUsername'
DB_PASSWORD='someCoolPassword'
```

Make sure you are able to log in through your CMD with `mysql -u root -p` and getting in successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Did all the thigs and finally I surrounded username and password with quotes

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME='username'
DB_PASSWORD='password'
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case i am using password contain "#" symbol , I have converted

```
DB_PASSWORD= "Special#"
```

Inside = "" It solves

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by creating a new MySQL user and database. Open your terminal and do the following:

```
sudo mysql --user=root mysql

CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Change the 'username' and 'password' to your preferred choices. Then grant privileges to this user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Finally, create the database;

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

Modify your .env file with the new credentials

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD='password'
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously made databases on phpmyadmin with a different username and password, your local host account needs a new user to have a different password. I tried the username and password that I've used previously and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I also encountered the same error, you can refer here:**

```
// config your host-name
APP_URL=http://test.demo

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
// default phpmyadmin display: localhost:3306
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I just **add the password** of my username in the **.env** file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had such problem. I created a new database by

```
CREATE DATABASE askiDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Then in the navigator console of MySQL Workbench I selected this database and in the administrative roles tab selected all Roles. Then I set a password in the login tab.
Moreover, in .env file of the project I set the DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD of this file correctly.
Then I execute the below command
    php artisan migrate

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel using Docker

1: Remove all images and volumes

```
./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v
```

2: Recreate the images and volumes

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

There are many variations of solutions for this problem. I hope this one helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message and i found out the error was caused by incorrect credentials.

the following credential was getting error
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),

The correct credential below solved the problem.
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),

Answer (score 0):

You must create new file **".env"** , copy contents from .env.example and past to .env, edit your paths, and wrtie php artisan migrate. This command run for me.

I have hard work, laravel 5.4 to 9.* :)

Answer (score 0):

First run

```bash
mysql -u root -p
```

Then issue following queries:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE database_name;

CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'%';
```

Answer (score -1):

open **config/database.php** and add your password here:

```
'mysql' => [
...,
'password' => ''
...])
```