# Am getting error when migrating Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

using MySQL database and  has PHP 7.4*

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
> where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and
> table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169240/php-artisan-migrate-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-laravell)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to turn MySQL on in order to use it.

Comment: If MySQL wasn't on, OP would get a different error. OP has the wrong credentials.

Comment: @ceejayoz MySQL is on

Comment: @patrickngare Yes, I know. You either have the wrong password, or your `root` user is passwordless, or you have the wrong user. It's a credentials issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz   My username is root and password is empty my .env looks like   
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=learn
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: @patrickngare `using password: YES` implies a password is set. In `php artisan tinker`, check your database settings via `config('database')`. You may need to clear the config cache.

Answer (score 0):

i'll tell you my experience, i had the same problem with laravel. check the port of mysql, if you have xampp or wampp or other server. and then go to the file .env and write the port number and save, probably if you changed the port number, eg:3307, you need to add it in .env. i did it and worked.