# I cannot store my data in database. I am tired of getting this localhost error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cannot store my data in database. I am tired of getting this localhost error
Changing passwords and creating new databases did not help for me. I tried many possible ways solving this

**Error I got in terminal**

```
PS C:\Programming\Laravel\DailyTaskApp> php artisan migrate
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = daily_task_app and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
  at C:\Programming\Laravel\DailyTaskApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }
  1   C:\Programming\Laravel\DailyTaskApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")        
  2   C:\Programming\Laravel\DailyTaskApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=daily_task_app", "root", "root", [])
PS C:\Programming\Laravel\DailyTaskApp>
```

**.env file**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:JB0Pw8lHFyh0yjhyd4fYfY3W1ElXRQ52Xopcv0TWEkc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=daily_task_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**config.inc.php file of phpmyadmin**

```
<?php


/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'] [$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */

?>
```

Comment: Can you use phpMyAdmiin or does that also give errors

Comment: Maybe create another user for your database other than "root" and use it in your app.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169240/php-artisan-migrate-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-laravell

Comment: To save you some headache this is the page they found most of the useful answers in, https://veerasundar.com/blog/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp.html . Apparently there are _four_ places to set your password.

Comment: Do you `login` your `database` using credential what you share?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169240/php-artisan-migrate-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-laravell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill password of mysql root user.
if you forgot it then you must [reset](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-windows-linux) it

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do following changes to your .env file.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

may be your password should be blank.

In phpmydamin go to your_db > privalages to checkout username & password